# How does one use the essence grid responsively

Tags: essence

The essence CSS framework has a grid component. However, I do not know how to use it responsively. For instance, how do I specify options to the grid that is specific for phone, tablet and desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Use the classes that are explained in the "RESPONSIVE GRID" section of http://getessence.io/core/grid-system

Use the `brick` class and then add one or many of the following classes to specify the element's width on various platforms:

- `brick-X` for desktop
- `brick-X-tablet` for tablets
- `brick-X-mobile` for mobiles

  Where `X = 1...12`

As described in the Properties section, the thresholds are:

- `...mobile` has a max-width of 768px
- `...tablet` has a max-width of 1024px

Example:

```
<Block classes={'e-row'}>
 <Block classes={'brick brick-3 brick-6-tablet brick-12-mobile'}>brick-3 brick-6-tablet brick-12-mobile</Block>
 <Block classes={'brick brick-6 brick-6-tablet brick-12-mobile'}>brick-6 brick-6-tablet brick-12-mobile</Block>
 <Block classes={'brick brick-6 brick-12-tablet brick-12-mobile'}>brick-6 brick-12-tablet brick-12-mobile</Block>
</Block>
```